# $GF(2^9)$ contains $GF(2^3)$ as only proper intermediate field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to show : $GF(2^9)$ contains $GF(2^3)$ as only proper intermediate field.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Sorry for being slow, but what is $GF(2^{9})$? You mean $GL(F_{2^{9}})$ or something? I have never seen this notation before.

Comment: @Bombyxmori $GF(p^n)$ is standard notation for $F_{p^n}$.

Comment: Hint: $3$ divides $9$.

Comment: Hi Ana!  I think you've misunderstood the point of the site.  It exists to help *you* find solutions to your problems, not to answer them for you.  You're more likely to get a useful answer if you tell us exactly what your question is, why you're interested in, what you've tried and where exactly you've got stuck.

Comment: Ok, Ana. What do you know about extensions of finite fields? Does the following result ring a bell? If $GF(q)$ is a subfield of $GF(Q)$, then $Q=q^n$ for some positive integer $n$. This task can be completed using that result, and not really without it, so...

Comment: But the others have a point. You should add some extra "context" to the question. Like a related example done in class? Did you try something, but it didn't work? Such pieces of information are needed, because only then we can explain to you how to make progress and understand what you are supposed to do here.

Comment: @Bombyxmori: $GF(q)$ is a common alternative notation for $\Bbb{F}_q$. For example coding theorists use it. Even in relatively recent texts. Our local number theorists also used it in the past, but I'm not sure about the current generation :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I see. May I ask what does $GF$ means at here? I have never seen it before.

Comment: @Bombyxmori: It is short for *Galois Field*.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thanks! I learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: put $L=\mathbb{F}_{2^9}$, the field of $512$ elements. Then $[L:\mathbb{F}_2]=9$. If $\mathbb{F}_2 \subset K \subset L$ is an intermediate field, then $[L:K] \mid [L:\mathbb{F}_2]$, so ...